# Accessing Postgres Docker DB through PGAdmin over local internet

Tags: postgresql, docker, dockerfile, docker-container, ubuntu-18.04

So I've built and run a postgres container from a dockerfile on a ubuntu server remotely. The container seems to be up and runing and I can access the db from psql on ubuntu. But I want to be able to connect to the DB remotely via PGadmin over the company network, so far im stuck in having to do it. I'm very new to both docker and Linux, I would really appreciate some help.

Heres a result of the docker ps:

[image: DOCKE PS RESULT]

Here is the code for the dockerfile:

```
FROM base.img:latest

RUN apt-get install postgresql postgresql-contrib -y 

# Run the rest of the commands as the ``postgres`` user created by the ``postgres-9.3`` package when it was ``apt-get installed``
USER postgres

# Copy the dump of table to container
ADD history.dump.2015  /tmp/

# Create a PostgreSQL role named ``docker`` with ``docker`` as the password and
# then create a database `docker` owned by the ``docker`` role.
# Note: here we use ``&&\`` to run commands one after the other - the ``\``
#       allows the RUN command to span multiple lines.
RUN    /etc/init.d/postgresql start &&\
   # psql --command "CREATE USER docker WITH SUPERUSER PASSWORD 'docker';" &&  createdb -O docker docker
     psql --command "ALTER USER postgres WITH PASSWORD 'abcdefg';"

# Adjust PostgreSQL configuration so that remote connections to the
# database are possible.
RUN echo "host all  all    0.0.0.0/0  md5" >> /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/pg_hba.conf

# And add ``listen_addresses`` to ``/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf``
RUN echo "listen_addresses='*'" >>  /etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf

# Expose the PostgreSQL port
EXPOSE 5432


# Set the default command to run when starting the container
CMD ["/usr/lib/postgresql/9.5/bin/postgres", "-D", "/var/lib/postgresql/9.5/main", "-c", "config_file=/etc/postgresql/9.5/main/postgresql.conf"]
```

Comment: Why not using the official postgresql docker image? it should be safer for you.  Managing container on a server only with docker is not really recommended. You should use an orchestrator tools for that.   Now. What is your issue ? from the server itself, you can connect to the PG via localhost:5432 ? and from your computer you cannot connect ? are your company firewall accept the connection on port 5432 from your computer to server?

Comment: Yes thats the issue, I can not connect from my own computer. Im on the company network through a vpn

Comment: Take you server external IP. If `psql -h the.external.server.ip ...` on the server connect then there is no issue on the server itself, but it is a more a network issue, like firewall as been closed.